# MongoError: not master: nodejs

Tags: mongodb

```
    const MONGODB_URL = MONGO_USER ?
  `mongodb://${​​​​​​MONGO_USER}​​​​​​:${​​​​​​encodeURIComponent(mongoPassword)}​​​​​​@${​​​​​​MONGO_HOST}​​​​​​:${​​​​​​MONGO_PORT}​​​​​​/${​​​​​​MONGO_DBNAME}​​​​​​` :
  `mongodb://${​​​​​​MONGO_HOST}​​​​​​:${​​​​​​MONGO_PORT}​​​​​​/${​​​​​​MONGO_DBNAME}​​​​​​`;
```

I have the above code to connect to mongo but I have a mongo cluster setup(primary and secondary), with the above one it is throwing an error: `
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: not master

how to check via nodejs that list the available hostnames and connect to the one which is having the primary role dynamically?

Comment: Specify replica set name as a URI option or more than one node in the host list.

Answer (score 0):

With a recent driver, use `directConnection=false` URI option.

With older drivers, specify replica set name as a URI option or more than one node in the host list.